# Problema con sentencia If anidadas en C

Tags: c, arduino

Estuve probando un ejemplo, sé que se pueden hacer con AND y de una manera más efectiva , pero en verdad no he encontrado información de por qué este programa no funciona, les dejo el programa en la parte de abajo, la idea es encontrar el mayor número , ya se que hay mejores maneras de realizar el codigo , solo que me dio curiosidad y no he encontrado una respuesta.

```
int n1 = 1; int n2 = 2; int n3 = 3; int m = 0; 
void setup() {   
// put your setup code here, to run once: 
   Serial.begin(9600);  }

void loop() {  if ( n1 > n2){   if(n1 > n3){
    m = n1;
    }   }

  else if ( n2 > n1){   if(n2 > n3){
    m = n2;
    }   }

  else{
    m = n2;
    }

    Serial.println(m); }
```

Answer (score 2):

> pero en verdad no he encontrado información de por que este programa no funciona ...

No explicas por qué el programa no funciona, así ya empezamos mal.

Aun así viendo el código entiendo que tu idea es que el programa elija el número más grande de entre tres a elegir.

Para resolver este problema con `if` anidados tendrías que añadir algo de código... ya que te falta un `else`:

```
if( n1 > n2 )
{
  if( n1 > n3 )
    m = n1;
  else // Si n1 no es mayor que n3, n3 es mayor que n1 y mayor, por tanto, que n2
    m = n3;
}
else if( n2 > n3 )
{
  m = n2;
}
else
{
  m = n3;
}
```

Por supuesto tambień puedes usar, como has comentado, operaciones *AND*:

```
if( (n1 > n2) && (n1 > n3) )
  m = n1;
else if( (n2 > n1) && (n2 > n3) )
  m = n2;
else
  m = n3;
```

Aunque también puedes pasar de toda esta lógica y optar por un modelo más sencillo:

```
m = n1 > n2 ? n1 : n2;
m = n3 > m  ? n3 : m;
```

Explicación del código anterior:

- En la primera línea elegimos el número más grande entre `n1` y `n2` y lo almacenamos en `m`
- En la segunda línea comparamos `m` con `n3` y elegimos el mayor de ambos
- El número almacenado en `m` será el mayor de los 3

Answer (score 0):

a mi entender si quieres solucionar el problema con sentencias de control `if else` es necesario agregar el comando `else` dentro del `else if`.

Tu código:

```
int n1 = 1; int n2 = 2; int n3 = 3; int m = 0; 
void setup() {   
// put your setup code here, to run once: 
   Serial.begin(9600);  }

void loop() {  if ( n1 > n2){   if(n1 > n3){
    m = n1;
    }   }

  else if ( n2 > n1){   if(n2 > n3){
    m = n2;
    }   }

  else{
    m = n2;
    }

    Serial.println(m); }
```

y quedaría algo así:

```
int n1 = 1, n2 = 2, n3 = 3, m = 0; 

void setup() {   
    // put your setup code here, to run once: 
    Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {

    if ( n1 > n2){          // si n1 es mayor que n2, entonces?
        if(n1 > n3){        // n1 es mayor, y si n1 es mayor a n3?
            m = n1;         // si n1 es mayor ahora m = n1
        }
    }else if( n2 > n1){     // cuando n1 sea menor, n2 será mayor a n1?
        if(n2 > n3){        // si n2 fuera mayor, n2 será mayor que n3?
            m = n2;         // si n2 es mayor, ahora m = n2
        }else{              // de lo contrario, y es esta condicional falta
            m = n3;         // m tomará el valor de n3 por no cumplirse la condición anterior
        }
    }else{                  
        m = n2;
    }

    Serial.println(m); 
}
```

Ahora, para pruebas prácticas de qué número es mayor y sin que se repitan los números anda perfecto, pero obviamente podrías mejorarlo para que el problema implique los números iguales (como tarea jajajajaja).

Saludos.

Comment: `if(n1 > n3)`... ¿ese `if` no necesita un `else`? ¿Y seguro que el último `else` está bien? ¿`m = n2`?  ¿No debería ser `m = n3`?

Comment: Claro tienes razón, pero el código que presentaste al comienzo faltaba un `else`, como indicaste que tenias un problema y quierías solucionarlo, se resolvía aplicando un `else`, ahora..., el código podría ser más eficiente aplicando AND o simplificando a menos condicionales e incluyendo la comparación `>=`

Comment: Yo no soy el que ha escrito la pregunta... soy el autor de la otra respuesta :)

Comment: Jajajajaja sorry, `error 300` saludos